# MySql escaped double quotes in string when exporting to csv

Tags: mysql, csv, export, mysql-workbench

I'm am having an issue with a record that contains a set of escaped double quotes inside a string when exporting my result set from MySql to a csv.

The record is showing correctly in the db:

[image: db]

however, when I export it to a csv, the result has the opening quote where the closing quote is supposed to be, and the closing quote at the end of the string:

[image: the result has the opening quote where the closing quote is supposed to be, and the closing quote at the end of the string].

Here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (hh_name) VALUES ("Sam \"FakeName\" & Lisa Smith");
```

Is there a way to enter the data so that the csv export shows the same way as it shows up in the db?

Comment: Show the code you use to export it.

Comment: It sounds like you're not quoting or escaping when you export.

Comment: I'm not using any code to export the results, just clicking on the 'Export/Import' button in the results section.

Comment: The results section of what? phpMyAdmin? Some other database GUI?

Comment: Sorry,  I should have mentioned that. I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Can you show the CSV file as plain text instead of from a spreadsheet? It's hard to tell if the problem is with how it's being exported or how it's being imported into the spreadsheet.